# How to create Polygon from Point (Spatial4j)

Tags: java, polygon, spatial, shapes

I want to do some geometric calculations in Java and found that [Spatial4j](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/locationtech.spatial4j) should suit my needs.

I want to be able to compute stuff like whether two polygons overlap or what their bounding box is.

My thinking is that I need to create a polygon from a series of points.

To that end I have tested with this code:

```
Point point1 = shapeFactory.pointXY(0, 0);
Point point2 = shapeFactory.pointXY(5, 1);
Point point3 = shapeFactory.pointXY(3, 3);
Point point4 = shapeFactory.pointXY(0, 1);
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.addAll(Arrays.asList(point1, point2, point3, point4));
```

So, I have my points now. How do I go about making a polygon (or for that matter any shape) from these points ?

I would think that `shapeFactory.polygon()` would create me a polygon but that throws me an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Any help ?

Comment: Where is the source for Shape4j ? I can't even find this.

Comment: My bad, messed up the name. It should be `Spatial4j`. I'll edit this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, it seems that Spatial4j does not connect the points, so it is not a filled shape. Instead I relied on the Spatial4j implementation of JTS and that did the trick. (Spatial4j's polygon is not implemented).

```
JtsSpatialContextFactory jtsSpatialContextFactory = new JtsSpatialContextFactory();
JtsSpatialContext jtsSpatialContext = jtsSpatialContextFactory.newSpatialContext();
JtsShapeFactory jtsShapeFactory = jtsSpatialContext.getShapeFactory();
ShapeFactory.PolygonBuilder polygonBuilder = jtsShapeFactory.polygon();
// note due to it being a builder one needs to chain the points.
Shape shape1 = polygonBuilder.pointXY(4, 0).pointXY(3, 3).pointXY(1, 4).pointXY(0, 0).pointXY(4, 0).build();
```

Now doing for example `shape.getArea()` returns the surface area.
One can also create a `Geometry` from a `Shape` by doing `jtsShapeFactory.getGeometryFrom(shape)`, which then returns a `Geometry`.

Note: Watch out with doing `polygonBuilder.pointXY()` even after calling `build()`. It will still append these points to whatever was chained to the builder before the `build`.